# Cloudflare subdomain to Digital ocean droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudflare, droplet

I am trying to point subdomain from cloudflare to digital ocean droplet. In Cloudflare, I created a record below but nothing happens do I need to do something more?

Type   Name        Value
A      subdomain   Droplet IP

Comment: I just experienced the same thing. What worked for me is when I updated my local DNS lookup ips to the following: 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Because my local dns lookup ip was something else the cloudflare one haven't propagated to that one yet but those ones work fine